# how to upgrade develop toolset on CentOS6.3 without the Internet?

Tags: linux, gcc, vim, centos, youcompleteme

*Background: My CentOS have no access to the Internet and upgrading OS isn't permitted, but I can upload files to it. I want to use [YCM](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) to complete my c++ code.*

I intended to install YCM on centos6.3 which have a clang2.8, but YCM needs libcalng3.9. So I have to upgrade my clang and llvm. Then I follow [this tutorail](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) to install llvm with source code, however I found that gcc cmake and many other fundamental tools also must be upgraded, or many errors would occur.

In order to install new tool chain, I have downloaded CentOS7.iso and use it as a local yum repo to upgrade development toolset. I don't know whether this way is proper, and it falt into loop dependence. So my questions are below.

1. Can install YCM without upgrade my development toolset?
2. Is there an easy/hard way to upgrade my development toolset?
3. What is the reason that I can't install software on CentOS6.3 using CentOS7.4?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use scientific linux's devtoolset packages from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-7/
2. Use rpm or yum to install devtoolset-7 and its dependecies. New binaries will be installed into /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin. To make use of them you must add the path to the PATH environment variable.
3. The packages contain prebuilt binaries which require specific versions of shared librarirs, which are not available on mismatched version of centos.